# Filling table matches multilayer from buffer in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, buffer

I have some tables in Postgis of differents geometries (Points, Lines, Polygons).

I create a buffer of 1 kilometer of one point with this:

```
ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3056563.45195278 804692.195990143)',48402), 1000) AS buffer
```

What i want to do is populate a new table with the results of my layers(tables in postgis) that are inside of the buffer.

I test with this query and it works, but only if found matches in all the tables.

```
    SELECT * FROM
         table1,
         table2,
  ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3056563.45195278804692.195990143)',48402),1000) AS buffer 
    WHERE
      ST_Within (buffer, table1.geom) AND
      ST_Within (buffer, table2.geom)
```

The idea is give some point or polygon with a buffer in the map. And return a table with all the matches from table1, table2, table3, table4 that are inside that buffer.

How can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a `UNION`, not a join, which is what you have. `UNION` just concatenates the results from each query into a single result.

So you'd do something like,

```
WITH buffer AS (
    SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(3056563.45195278804692.195990143)',48402),1000) AS geom
)
SELECT table1.geom FROM table1, buffer WHERE ST_Within(table1.geom, buffer.geom)
UNION
SELECT table2.geom FROM table2, buffer WHERE ST_Within(table2.geom, buffer.geom)
UNION
[etc...]
```

This query returns rows with geometries from each table that are entirely within the buffer. I haven't given any consideration to the *type* of geometries I'm returning, but that wasn't part of your question.

I've used `WITH` here to create the buffer object so that I can reuse it. I refer to it in my queries as if it were a table with a geometry column.

Note that the order of arguments to `ST_Within` is *contained geometry*, *containing geometry*, not the other way around. Also note that for a `UNION`, the columns returned from each query have to match the columns for the others -- if the table definitions are different for each table, you'll have to explicitly name the columns.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works perfect, is awesome the clause "WITH", very usefull, i just change the FROM part of query, because i get an error. It work adding the buffer in the FROM like this: FROM table1, buffer WHERE...

Comment: Glad it worked. (Also thanks for noticing the missing table ref. I updated the answer.)